# Angularjs $http requests are passed without finishing it's job

Tags: angularjs, http, service

Hi i am using angularjs 1.6 in my projects and i have a problem with $http requests or i don't know what's happening there. I will try to explain the problem below;

```
app.controller('ctname', function($scope, fcname){

  $scope.calledFunc = function(){

    fcname.serviceFunction(12).then(function(response){
      if(response.data != null){
        //fill modal's model here 
      }
    });

    //Open modal
    $('#SomeModal').modal('show');

  };

})
.factory('fcname', function($http){
var fac = {};

fac.serviceFunction= function (someId) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Home/someBackEndMethod',
            data: JSON.stringify({ _someId: someId}),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };

return fac;
});
```

What exactly happening is my modal opens before service do it's job so my modal sometimes opens empty. Is there anything i can do about this ?

Comment: `$http` service handles requests as asynchronous callbacks. The data can arrive in just few milliseconds or in a minute. So `$('#SomeModal').modal('show')` is executed **before** `fcname.serviceFunction(12)` is resolved. You probably need to open your modal inside `.then()` when data arrives (or in `.finally()`, for both success and error responses)

Comment: It's because your modal opens before your service function.You can use promise OR you can open ` if(response.data != null){$('#SomeModal').modal('show');}` inside your success.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, should i replace .then() with .finally() or will check the syntax for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript and the AngularJS framework use non-blocking asynchronous I/O. **Subsequent code always executes** before the event handlers furnished to those I/O operations.

Code that needs to be executed after an I/O operation needs to be put **inside** an event handler:

```
app.controller('ctname', function($scope, fcname){

  $scope.calledFunc = function(){

    fcname.serviceFunction(12)
      .then(function(response){
        if(response.data != null){
           //fill modal's model here 
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).finally(function() {            
        //Open modal
        $('#SomeModal').modal('show');
    });

  };

})
```

Put the code inside either the original `.then` block or a subsequent [chained](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) block.

Comment: Thanks for your interest also all the information this looks ok, i will try.